# How to use transit mode in google maps

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on google maps api. I need to show the map according to travel modes. I have four modes car, bicycle, walking and train. Google map loads according to selected mode. My first 3 options are working fine but how i can pass train in transit mode. Please help me.

```
travel_mode = jQuery('#mode').val();        
if(a==="")
  this.showAlert(this.options.msgEmpty); 
else
{
  a= {
    origin:a,
    destination:new google.maps.LatLng(this.options.lat,this.options.lng),
    travelMode:google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode[travel_mode]
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to use transit `travelMode`.

```
google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT
```

And set `transitOptions` to prefer train.

```
a= {
  origin: a,
  destination: new google.maps.LatLng(this.options.lat, this.options.lng),
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT,
  transitOptions: {
    modes: [google.maps.TransitMode.TRAIN]
  }
};
```

See `transitOptions` [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#TransitOptions).

> **google.maps.TransitMode.TRAIN** indicates that the calculated route should prefer travel by train.